# How could I deal with this below state please?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have 3 lists are

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001]
z = [100,200,300,400]
```

I need to choose like this :

```
state1:

1 --->0.1--->100
1 --->0.1--->200
1 --->0.1--->300
1 --->0.1--->400
==============
state2:

1 --->0.01--->100
1 --->0.01--->200
1 --->0.01--->300
1 --->0.01--->400
.
.
.
.
.
5 --->0.0001--->100
5 --->0.0001--->200
5 --->0.0001--->300
5 --->0.0001--->400
```

And in every state of choosing, I need to put them in this snippet below:

```
params = {'n_estimators': 100, 'max_depth':1, 'min_samples_split': 2,
          'learning_rate': 0.1, 'loss': 'ls'}
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
mse = mean_squared_error(a4, clf.predict(a3))
mae=mean_absolute_error(a4,clf.predict(a3))
r2=r2_score(a4, clf.predict(a3))
def mape_vectorized(a, b): 
    mask = a != 0
    return (np.fabs(a[mask] - b[mask])/a[mask]).mean()
print("MAPE:%.5f" %mape_vectorized(a4, clf.predict(a3)))
print("MAE: %.5f" % mae)
print("MSE: %.5f" % mse)
print("R2:  %.5f" % r2)
```

And print the results to every state. Instead of doing them manually and choose element by element from every state and it will take time. Could anyone help me with this matter, please?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I need n_estimators to take z values. 'max_depth' takes x values. 'learning_rate': takes y values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate each state using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]
z = [100, 200, 300, 400]

for s in itertools.product(x, y, z):
    print(s)
```

Each state from the generator can then be used as argument to feed in your regressions.

Comment: Yes, now it is ok and it gives me this (1, 0.1, 100)(1, 0.1, 200)................etc. How could I choose for example the elements from every tuple to compensate in my program?